# append data retrieved from API for loop to array

Tags: swift, xcode, api, loops, append

I'm having issues using a for loop to append data retrieved from an API to an array. I am attempting to use the array to dequeue cells in a tableview. I edited the question to comply with the answer provided but received errors at numberofrowsinsection (placed integer to check for more errors) and cellforrowat.

This is code in the view controller:

```
  class BusinessesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var businesses: [Business] = []

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Business.searchWithTerm(term: "Restaurants", sort: .distance, categories: nil) { (businesses, error) in
        self.businesses = businesses!


    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return businesses.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Business") as! SelectTableViewCell
    let business = businesses[indexPath.row]
    cell.BusinessName.text = business.name

    return cell
}


}
```

this is current console printout returned

```
["sort_by": distance, "open_now": 0, "term": Restaurants, "location": 37.785771,-122.406165]
Optional([<Decided.Business: 0x600000123520>, <Decided.Business: 0x600000123700>, <Decided.Business: 0x600000123c00>, <Decided.Business: 0x600000123ca0>, <Decided.Business: 0x600000123b60>, <Decided.Business: 0x604000124060>, <Decided.Business: 0x6040001241a0>, <Decided.Business: 0x604000124240>, <Decided.Business: 0x6040001244c0>, <Decided.Business: 0x604000124560>, <Decided.Business: 0x604000124600>, <Decided.Business: 0x600000123f20>, <Decided.Business: 0x6040001246a0>, <Decided.Business: 0x604000124740>, <Decided.Business: 0x6040001247e0>, <Decided.Business: 0x604000124880>, <Decided.Business: 0x600000124240>, <Decided.Business: 0x6000001242e0>, <Decided.Business: 0x600000124380>, <Decided.Business: 0x6000001244c0>])
```

This is the model I am using:

```
import UIKit

class Business: NSObject {
let name: String?
let address: String?
let imageURL: URL?
let categories: String?
let distance: String?
let ratingImage: UIImage?
let reviewCount: NSNumber?

init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
    name = dictionary["name"] as? String

    let imageURLString = dictionary["image_url"] as? String
    if imageURLString != nil {
        imageURL = URL(string: imageURLString!)
    } else {
        imageURL = nil
    }

    let location = dictionary["location"] as? NSDictionary
    var address = ""
    if location != nil {
        let addressArray = location!["display_address"] as? NSArray
        if addressArray != nil {
            if addressArray!.count > 0 {
                address = addressArray![0] as! String
            }
            if addressArray!.count > 1 {
                address += ", " + (addressArray![1] as! String)
            }
        }
    }
    self.address = address

    let categoriesArray = dictionary["categories"] as? [NSDictionary]
    if categoriesArray != nil {
        var categoryNames = [String]()
        for category in categoriesArray! {
            let categoryName = category["title"] as! String
            categoryNames.append(categoryName)
        }
        categories = categoryNames.joined(separator: ", ")
    } else {
        categories = nil
    }

    let distanceMeters = dictionary["distance"] as? NSNumber
    if distanceMeters != nil {
        let milesPerMeter = 0.000621371
        distance = String(format: "%.2f mi", milesPerMeter * distanceMeters!.doubleValue)
    } else {
        distance = nil
    }

    let rating = dictionary["rating"] as? Double
    if rating != nil {
        switch rating {
            case 1:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_1")
                break
            case 1.5:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_1half")
                break
            case 2:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_2")
                break
            case 2.5:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_2half")
                break
            case 3:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_3")
                break
            case 3.5:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_3half")
                break
            case 4:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_4")
                break
            case 4.5:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_4half")
                break
            case 5:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_5")
                break
            default:
                self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_0")
                break
        }
    } else {
        self.ratingImage = UIImage(named: "stars_0")
    }

    reviewCount = dictionary["review_count"] as? NSNumber
}

class func businesses(array: [NSDictionary]) -> [Business] {
    var businesses = [Business]()
    for dictionary in array {
        let business = Business(dictionary: dictionary)
        businesses.append(business)
    }
    return businesses
}

class func searchWithTerm(term: String, completion: @escaping ([Business]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    _ = YelpClient.sharedInstance.searchWithTerm(term, completion: completion)
}

class func searchWithTerm(term: String, sort: YelpSortMode?, categories: [String]?, completion: @escaping ([Business]?, Error?) -> Void) -> Void {
    _ = YelpClient.sharedInstance.searchWithTerm(term, sort: sort, categories: categories, openNow: false, completion: completion)
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate with the details I.e. compilation error or behaviour

Comment: console printout is showing behavior, when I append the same data reappears due to the loop, I do not know how to fix this. for example Hot Dog Stand 13 Hot Dog StandAnnie's Hot Dog Cart 33. "Hot Dog Stand" is repeated in every printout. I want the data to print one time with all the names and the correct number of names.

Comment: It looks like you are looping through an array and calling print on each iteration. Try moving your print statement outside of the for loop

Comment: this is new print out from console updating code above now

Comment: ["sort_by": distance, "open_now": 0, "term": Restaurants, "location": 37.785771,-122.406165]
Hot Dog StandAnnie's Hot Dog CartJohn's GrillAnnie's Hot Dogs & PretzelsTads Steak RestaurantBoudin Bakery & CafeDirty HabitConfetti Cafe at Macy'sWolfgang Puck PizzaBoudin Bakery & CafeKing Of Thai Noodle HouseSorabol Korean RestaurantBluestem BrasserieSF BistroCaffe MioWishboneLobster MEPasta MotoFire of Brazil ExpressTap415 328

Comment: I can’t see your declaration of `self.Names` but it looks like it’s a string. It seems like you may want an array of strings instead I.e. `[String]`

Comment: code above edited

Comment: You might also want to move your `reloadData()` outside of your for loop as well.

Comment: same results occur

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: i guess you are calling that api more than from viewdidload. you calling from viewdidload and from searching functions. let me know if thats the case

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen I am using the model in the view controller business

Comment: @kathayatnk I am not expecting the correct output with the code that was previously posted but I want it to output the following, the names of the restaurants without repetition and a correct count of them.

Comment: I See you changed the code  and you are not appending to Names anymore. The index out of range is due to the _return 16_ statement. Make it _return businesses.count_ .

Comment: @kathayatnk ok the application no longer crashes but it is not returning anything from the api fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main mistake is that you are declaring `Names` as a `String`.

After appending `Hot Dog Stand` the table view is creating 13 cells because the string has 13 characters which is returned in `numberOfRows`.

You probably want

```
 Business.searchWithTerm(term: "Restaurants", sort: .distance, categories: nil) { (businesses, error) in
       if let error = error { print(error); return }
       self.businesses = businesses!
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
 }
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return businesses.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Business") as! SelectTableViewCell
    let business = businesses[indexPath.row]
    cell.BusinessName.text = business.name

    return cell
}
```

and delete the `Names` property

Comment: thanks but it didn't work I edited the question to reflect your changes

Comment: @OmarAl-Eisa You are still calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` outside the completion block. Check how @vaidan is calling inside the completion block.

Comment: Never hardcode the return value of  `numberOfRows`, do not return `16`. return `businesses.count`. Please read my suggestion carefully. And you have to call `reloadData()` **in** the closure. I added also a dispatch block to reload the table view on the main thread.

Comment: @vadian ok application no longer crashes yet it also no longer returns any data from the api fetch

Comment: Have you moved `reloadData()` **into** the closure? According to your edited code you haven't. Consider that `searchWithTerm` works **asynchronously**.